# Calling selected checbox method inside a datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a data grid which one of the item in the item source is a bool variable.

the datagrid translate the bool into a checkbox.

I want to know how to add the event checkbox click on the checkbox inside the data grid?

here is my code:

```
public class FilterMcode
{
    private bool cb;

    public bool Cb
    {
        get { return cb; }
        set { cb = value; }
    }
    private string mcode;

    public string Mcode
    {
        get { return mcode; }
        set { mcode = value; }
    }

    private string structureName;

    public string StructureName
    {
        get { return structureName; }
        set { structureName = value; }
    }

    public FilterMcode()
    {
        cb = true;
        structureName = "";
        mcode = "";
    }
}

public class Main ()
{
    private  List<FilterMcode> _qf;

    update void updateDataGrid()
    {
            DataGridCommands.ItemsSource = _qf;
            DataGridCommands.Items.Refresh();

    // calling check box click????
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the check box you want to change its IsChecked? can you publish your xaml?

Comment: the checkbox is the variable CB. when it turn into column it turns into checkbox.

Comment: Are you specifically looking to subscribe to Click event or you need to subscribe to CheckedChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tru to use the INotifyPropertyChanged, then each time the checkbox will be checked the CB property will be updated.

**Like That:**

```
/// <summary>
/// implements the INotifyPropertyChanged (.net 4.5)
/// </summary>
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class FilterMcode:BaseObservableObject
{
    private bool cb;

    public bool Cb
    {
        get { return cb; }
        set
        {
            cb = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string mcode;

    public string Mcode
    {
        get { return mcode; }
        set
        {
            mcode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string structureName;

    public string StructureName
    {
        get { return structureName; }
        set
        {
            structureName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public FilterMcode()
    {
        cb = true;
        structureName = "";
        mcode = "";
    }
}
```

**Then change your main class in next manner**

```
public class Main
{
    private List<FilterMcode> _qf;

    public void updateDataGrid()
    {
        _qf.ForEach(mcode => mcode.PropertyChanged += McodeOnPropertyChanged);
        DataGridCommands.ItemsSource = _qf;
        DataGridCommands.Items.Refresh();

        // calling check box click????
    }

    private void McodeOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.PropertyName != "Cb" ) return;
        //Add your logic here
    }
}
```

This is the simplies way to get what you want. There are a number of downwards:

1. You have to unsubscribe the event.
2. This is not an MVVM way to work with the wpf.

Regards.